# ElasticBeanstalk Environment Variables not accessible using pm2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pm2

I have successfully been able to run my application on ElasticBeanstalk using the basic npm start script shown below.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www"
}
```

On my server I have now installed pm2 globally and updated the `start` script in my `package.json` to use pm2.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "pm2 start ./bin/www"
}
```

pm2 starts the process, I can see this from looking at my logs however it does not seem to have access to the environment variables I set for ElasticBeanstalk. I set the environment variables with the  [aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html) option in the file `.ebextensions/options.config` shown below.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    keyOne: foo
    keyTwo: bar
    keyThree: foo
```

pm2 complains about not being able to read a property of undefined for an environment variable.

```
0|www    | TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyOne' of undefined
0|www    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/app.js:26:38)
0|www    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
0|www    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
0|www    |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
0|www    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
0|www    |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
0|www    |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/var/app/current/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39)
0|www    |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
0|www    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/bin/www:7:11)
0|www    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

Do I need to source a file first? I would like to avoid setting environment variables in a ecosystem.config.js file for pm2 as I can also manage the environment variables at the moment in a visual way from the AWS console using the approach currently implemented.

Comment: How exactly do you access the environment variables on `/var/app/current/app.js:26:38`? Just `process.env.keyOne` ?

Comment: Yep that is it, I have a config.js file that makes a decision to read production or development env vars, but the actual reading in of them is `process.env.keyOne`

Comment: Could you edit your question to include `config.js`?

Comment: Did you source them as you asked about this? Usually you would have to do this.

Answer (score -1):

If you already created the PM2 process and then updated environment variables, you should delete the PM2 process and create it again using ecosystem file.

The delete and create actions consider newly created environment variables, but not the restart. I don't know why.

Comment: PM2 has a specif CLI command to restart AND reload ENV variables, which is not the standard. IIRC it is the `--reload-env` flag